# How to change the default view in MS Excel 2013 to 80%

Tags: microsoft-excel

Every time I open a new workbook or worksheet in Microsoft Excel, I find myself adjusting the view to my preferred view of 80%. Is there a way to make 80% the default?

I have tried two things, which haven't worked:

1. Saving book.xltx and sheet.xltx in XLSTART folder
2. In Excel Options, changing the default criteria for when a new workbook opens (no option for % view here)

Perhaps I am doing step #1 wrong or there is more to do there OR I need to use VBA and I'm not sure how to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you stackoverflow community!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a macro in your Personal.xlsb. If you don't know whether that is active, follow these steps:

Start the Macro Recorder and in the "Record Macro" dialog select "Personal Macro Workbook" in the drop-down for "Store macro in". Set the name as ZoomLevel80. Hit OK and set the Zoom level to 80%. Stop the macro recorder.

Now hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the Visual Basic Editor. On the left, find the VBA Project (Personal.xlsb). In the "Modules" section you will find a module with the macro you just recorded, but we can leave that alone.

Select the "This Workbook" module and in the code window put this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
End Sub
```

[image]

Click the Save icon. Now close Excel. The personal macro workbook is loaded every time Excel starts. The macro code above will run every time this macro workbook is opened.

The Zoom level is stored with each workbook, though, so when you open another workbook that was not set to 80% zoom, you can use the recorded macro. Assign a keyboard shortcut to the macro: Click the "Macros" icon on the Developer ribbon. Select the macro ZoomLevel80, click the Options button and enter a keyboard shortcut, for example Ctrl-8.

The screenshots have been taken with 2010, but the same principle applies in 2013.

Comment: Hi, an issue for me, albeit ten years hence.  On opening excel or a workbook, getting the following error:
Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set.
On clicking debug, it takes me to the following section:
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
    
End Sub
and highlights ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80.
Excel version 2303 (Build 16277.20280).

Comment: @agftrading Please read [ask] and then post your own question instead of putting it in the comments of a ten year old answer. Sheesh, people these days <shakeshead>.

Comment: The solution provided in this answer does not work today in the context described above.  This should be helpful for anyone else here today and experiencing the same issue and prompt updated answers as appropriate.  Here is to helping the community.  All the best.

Comment: If you want to help the community and get an answer for current versions, the better approach would be to ask a new question, refer to this ten year old question, then ask for an approach that works for current versions. Nobody will update an answer because you post a comment after ten years.

Comment: If only we knew where the person that posted the original answer was; guess after all this time, it is extremely unlikely that they would ever see a comment.  Ah well, at least if anyone else finds their way to this page, the comment should be helpful.  All the best.

Comment: @agftrading I get pinged when someone comments on one of my old answers, but that does not mean that I am obliged to keep any old answers up to par with evolving technology. You may want to try answering a few questions yourself. Then you might realize that it is a lot of work for us unpaid volunteers, and you might curb your expectations and drop the snarky comments. Just saying.